# The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I am trying to do unit test on a function. Here is the production code :

```
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      _responseRestaurantsModel =
          ResponseRestaurantsModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);
      if (_responseRestaurantsModel.documents.isEmpty)
        throw NoResultFoundException();
      return _responseRestaurantsModel;
    } else {
      throw ServerException();
    }
```

Here `_responseRestaurantsModel.documents` is a `List`, and I am throwing an exception if it is empty.

Here is the test code :

```
class MockResponseRestaurantModel extends Mock implements ResponseRestaurantsModel {}

  setUp(() {
    mockHttpClient = MockHttpClient();
    dataSource = RestaurantRemoteDataSourceImpl(mockHttpClient);
    tResponseRestaurantModel = MockResponseRestaurantModel();
  });

    test(
      'should throw NoResultFoundException when the list is empty',
      () async {
        // arrange
        when(tResponseRestaurantModel.documents.isEmpty).thenReturn(null);

        // act
        final call = dataSource.getRestaurants;
        // assert
        expect(
          () => call(params....), throwsA(TypeMatcher<NoResultFoundException>()),
        );
      },
    );
```

But the test fails showing **ERROR: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'isEmpty' was called on null.** Whats wrong here ?

```
class ResponseRestaurantsModel {
  List<RestaurantModel> documents;
  MetaRestaurantsModel meta;

  ResponseRestaurantsModel({@required this.documents, @required this.meta});

  ResponseRestaurantsModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    if (json['documents'] != null) {
      documents = new List<RestaurantModel>();
      json['documents'].forEach((v) {
        documents.add(new RestaurantModel.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    meta = json['meta'] != null
        ? new MetaRestaurantsModel.fromJson(json['meta'])
        : null;
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    if (this.documents != null) {
      data['documents'] = this.documents.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
    }
    if (this.meta != null) {
      data['meta'] = this.meta.toJson();
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

Model Class :

Comment: Well, the `documents` property contains a `null` value. It is impossible to help you since you don't show any code which sets the `documents` property (e.g. how the JSON are parsed).

Comment: @julemand101 I have added the model class now.

Comment: Ok, but if `json['documents']` is `null` you will set `documents` to `null`. So you should maybe look at the JSON? Or, if it is intentional that there are no document, you need to set the variable to an empty list if you want to be able to call `.isEmpty` on it.

Comment: @julemand101 Set to an empty list

Comment: Well, then define the `document` property as: `List<RestaurantModel> documents = [];` and remove `documents = new List<RestaurantModel>();`. Then `documents` will always be defined in the `ResponseRestaurantsModel` object.

Comment: Still getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218686/discussion-between-julemand101-and-newaj).

Answer (score 1):

`tResponseRestaurantModel.documents` is null, so you have to add this property to your `MockResponseRestaurantModel`

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this :

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
  _responseRestaurantsModel =
      ResponseRestaurantsModel.fromJson(jsonResponse);
  if (_responseRestaurantsModel?.documents?.isEmpty ?? true)
    throw NoResultFoundException();
  return _responseRestaurantsModel;
} else {
  throw ServerException();
}
```

Comment: Already tried that. It then says `statusCode` was called on `null`. But thats not definitely.